# Python: Pandas Groupby then fail rate

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having troubles using groupby then trying to get the error rate for the following:

```
label success
Ls1 true
Ls2 false
Ls2 false
Ls1 true
Ls3 true
Ls4 true
Ls4 false
```

what i would like to see is something like below

```
label %failed
Ls1 0
Ls2 100
Ls3 0
Ls4 50
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mean` per groups but invert mask by `~`, then multiple by `100` and convert `Series` to `Dataframe` by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df = (~df['success']).groupby(df['label']).mean().mul(100).reset_index(name='%failed')
print (df)
  label  %failed
0   Ls1      0.0
1   Ls2    100.0
2   Ls3      0.0
3   Ls4     50.0
```

Another idea is subtract `100` from right side by [`Series.rsub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rsub.html):

```
df = df.groupby('label')['success'].mean().mul(100).rsub(100).reset_index(name='%failed')
print (df)
  label  %failed
0   Ls1      0.0
1   Ls2    100.0
2   Ls3      0.0
3   Ls4     50.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dd1=pd.crosstab(df1.label,df1.success,normalize="index")
(dd1.iloc[:,1].rename("%failed").astype(int)*100).reset_index()

：

 label  %failed
0   Ls1      100
1   Ls2        0
2   Ls3      100
3   Ls4        0
```